# When I am trying to use django-newsletter, I have error while trying to install according to docs

Tags: python, django

I was trying to create a subscription app in django, so I try to use the django-newsletter. But I have some error and I don't know why.

```
./manage.py runserver
```

It was giving me error like this:

```
File "./manage.py", line 16
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My urls.py code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^newsletter/', include('newsletter.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'newsletter',
]
```

Comment: Show your manage.py module, please.

Comment: The original one. I didn't change anything. 
def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myblog.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)